# Android - passing Intents back and forth

Tags: android, android-intent

I have two activities: `activity_main` and `activity_takeapicture`. I start an intent from `activity_main` and the other activity takes a picture. Then `activity_takeapicture` sends another intent with the file back to `activity_main`. In `activity_main` should I use `onActivityResult` method to catch the intent sent by `activity_takeapicture` and subsequently receive the data? Here is the part that sends the intent in `activity_main`:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayResult.class);
    startActivity(intent);
```

And here is 'activity_takeapicture`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, pictureFile);
        startActivity(intent);
```

**EDIT:** I have tried what you guys said, but now `onActivityResult` doesn't fire when the `activity_takeapicture` returns the intent back. How do I fix that?

Comment: Funny, I searched for the exact same thing last night. I found this: [How to manage start activity for result on Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/how-to-manage-start-activity-for-result-on-android)

Comment: @ÜberLem Now I have the app just crash with no error message.

Comment: Oh. It was caught. That's why no error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `activity_takeapicture` saves the picture on the device SD card, you can use the following.

```
intent.putExtra("SavedImageDirectory", filepath); //this will save the file path
```

then in your `activity_main` you can use

```
//this will get the file path of the saved image
String ImageDirectory = getIntent().getStringExtra("SavedImageDirectory"); 

//this will decode the filepath into a bitmap 
Bitmap bp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(ImageDirectory);

//this will display the bitmap on your imageview on the `activity_main`
MyImageView.setImageDrawable(bp);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like that but you will have to close all of the intent that you left open to avoid memory uses and when you back press the you wont see over 9,000 activities xD
it wont avoid memory uses because it will close te Activity only after you return to it.

you can also use the alnActivityResult, this is better solution because you are not opening too much Activities and it is simple to you and to your user

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

In your Class inialize a static Variable

```
private static final int CAM_REQUEST = 1;
```

In your Button Listener Method

```
public void onClick(View v){
   Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
   startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, CAM_REQUEST);
}
```

And then in Your Activity Override this method:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
   if(requestCode == CAM_REQUEST){
      Bitmap thumbTaken = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
      yourImageView.setImageBitmap(thumbTaken);
   }
}
```

And dont forget to give permission for using CAMERA

Hope it helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `startActivity`. Use `startActivityForResult` instead.